# If $\sigma : H \xrightarrow{\sim} G $ is a group isomorphism and $H = \langle S \rangle$, then does $G = \langle \sigma(S)\rangle$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, prime-numbers, integers, prime-gaps

Let $\sigma : \Bbb{P} \xrightarrow{\sim} \Bbb{P}$ be a permutation of the primes $\Bbb{P} = \{ 2,3,5,7,11, \dots \}$.

Then $\sigma$ extends uniquely to a surjective group hom $\Bbb{Q}^{\times} \to \Bbb{Z}$, the group of integers.  We know that $\sigma$ acts as $\sigma(\dfrac{p_1 \cdots p_r}{q_1 \cdots q_s}) = \sum_{i = 1}^r \sigma(p_i) - \sum_{i=1}^s \sigma(q_i)$.  For now and for simplicity of argument take $\sigma = \text{id}$ the identity permutation.

So for instance $\ker \sigma \supset \langle\dfrac{pq}{rs} : \sigma(p) + \sigma(q) = \sigma(r) + \sigma(s) \rangle$.  Notice, that $\ker \sigma$ can contain no prime pair fraction $\dfrac{p}{q}$ for $p \neq q$ since $\sigma$ permutes primes and so $\sigma(p) \neq \sigma(q)$ whenever $p \neq q$.

Let $H = \langle \dfrac{p}{q}: p, q \text{ prime, and } \sigma(p) \gt \sigma(q)\rangle$ that of course includes all $\dfrac{p}{q}$ such that $\sigma(p) \lt \sigma(q)$ since generation is by $g^z$ for all $z \in \Bbb{Z}$ (including negative exponents) and $g \in $ the generating set.  Notice that multiplying a finite collection of generators results in the same imbalance i.e. $\sigma(p_1) + \dots + \sigma(p_r) \gt \sigma(q_1) + \dots + \sigma(q_r)$ whenever $\sigma(p_i) \gt \sigma(q_i)$ for each $i$.

Take a look at the cosets $\dfrac{a}{b}K$ of the kernel.  If $\dfrac{a}{b} \notin K$ then $\sigma(a) \gt \sigma(b)$ or $\sigma(b) \gt \sigma(a)$ which would mean $\dfrac{a}{b} \in H$.

> Thus, can we conclude that $H \simeq \Bbb{Q}^{\times}/K \simeq \Bbb{Z}$?  In particular, the first isomorphism is in question.

Then what can we say about prime gaps, if anything?  Since $S = \{ \dfrac{p}{q} : p, q \text{ both prime}, p \neq q\}$ is essentially all non-diagonal pairs of primes $(p,q)$ and $S$ generates $H$ as a group, which then maps isomorphically onto $\Bbb{Z}$.  If $H = \langle S \rangle \simeq \Bbb{Z} = \langle 1 \rangle$.  Have we proved that since $\sigma(3) - \sigma(2) = 3 - 2 = 1 \implies \sigma^{-1}(1) = \dfrac{3}{2}$ so that $H = \langle \dfrac{3}{2}\rangle$?  In other words, the question is:

> If $\sigma : H \xrightarrow{\sim} G $ is a group isomorphism and $H = \langle S \rangle$, then does $G = \langle \sigma(S)\rangle$?

---

From the commenters we've learned that $H \cap K \neq \{1\}$.  For example $H \ni \dfrac{3}{5}, \dfrac{13}{11}$ and their product is in $K$.

Comment: Answer to present title: yes. Answer to question: none yet, I still haven't got through it.

Comment: @AnginaSeng, thanks!  It seems weird that $H$ would equal $\langle 3/2 \rangle$ after having a plethora of other things generating it.

Comment: Your map $\sigma$ is not a group homomorphism, and $H$ is not equal to $\langle 3/2\rangle$. Another way to describe $H$ is as the subgroup generated by those rationals whose numerator and denominator have the same number of prime factors (with multiplicity).

Comment: @TokenToucan where did I go wrong, since it seems like $H = \langle 3/2\rangle$ but not.

Comment: Oh I was mixing up addition and multiplication. But anyways, $H$ is not $\langle 3/2\rangle$ - for instance, $3/7$ is supposed to be in $H$ but it's definitely not in $\langle 3/2\rangle$.

Comment: What do you mean by $\mathbb{Z}^+$? Integers under addition? That notation is not good as it usually means the set of positive or nonnegative integers. Just write $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @AlgebraicGeometryStudent I don't really follow your argument for why $H$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Q^\times / K$ - for instance, you seem to implicitly want something like $\sigma (a) > \sigma(b)$ implies $a/b$ is in $H$ but I don't see how that would follow from the previous paragraph. For that isomorphism to work out (but we know it doesn't) you want the restriction to $H$ to be surjective (maybe true) and for $H$ to intersect $K$ trivially (I don't think this is the case)

Comment: @NajibIdrissi thanks.  I'ved fixed the issue, see post

Comment: @TokenToucan $p_1 \cdots p_r/(q_1 \cdots q_s) \in K \cap H \implies r = s$ by definition of $H$.  Now how can you have $\sigma(p_1) + \dots \sigma(p_r) = \sigma(q_1) + \dots + \sigma(q_r)$ as well as a pairing $p_{i_j}, q_{k_j}, j = 1..r$ such that $\sigma(p_{i_j}) \gt \sigma(q_{k_j})$.  For instance $3 + 13 = 11 + 5$ .  Then $3 \lt 11$ and $13 \gt 5$.  Then $13\cdot 3 / (11\cdot 5)$ so I see now :(

Comment: @AlgebraicGeometryStudent you have to allow inverses and so you must also permit $\sigma(p_{i_j}) < \sigma(q_{k_j})$ and that makes it even easier I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've asked two questions and made a few claims, I'll try to answer everything.

1. Yes, if $\sigma : H \to G$ is an isomorphism and $H$ is generated by $S$, then $G$ is generated by $\langle S \rangle$. Just write any element of $H$ as $h=s_1^{\pm} \dots s_k^{\pm}$ for $s_i \in S$, then $\sigma(h) = \sigma(s_1)^{\pm} \dots \sigma(s_k)^{\pm}$ belongs to $\langle S \rangle$.
2. No, we cannot conclude that $H \simeq \mathbb{Q}^\times / K$. I do not follow your argument, and since there is a gap it is difficult to pinpoint what is wrong, exactly. If you wanted to conclude that, you would essentially need to build a surjective morphism $\mathbb{Q}^\times \to H$ with kernel $K$. You have not done that.
3. I do not get your argument that $\sigma(a) > \sigma(b) \implies a/b \in H$. You have proved that if $a/b = p_1 \dots p_r / (q_1 \dots q_r)$ is a product of generators of $H$, then $\sigma(a) > \sigma(b)$. But you have not proved the converse.